# WebView - Scroll when using hardware controls rather than traversing page elements

Tags: android, webview

I have a `webView` being used in an AndroidTV app. The problem I'm having is that the native behaviour is for the focus to move through each element on a page being displayed when you navigate with the hardware controller. What I want is when you press down on the DPAD it will scroll the webView down rather than moving to the next object on the page the `webView` is displaying, as sometimes there can be 10+ focusable objects down the page before it would scroll which isn't a great user experience.

Technically it could be wrapped in a ScrollView but the developer documents strongly discourage wrapping scrollable items in ScrollViews as it's highly inefficient.

Is there a way to tell the `webView` not to let the individual elements on the page be focusable but let the `webView` itself still be focusable so it can scroll.

Comment: I have opposite problem on nvidia shield TV - remote controller scrolls webview but doesn't focus any web elements. So it looks like implementation thing with no way to choose desired behavior.

Comment: @PointerNull The fact that we're getting different behaviour would suggest that is a, possibly undocumented, setting/config we've inadvertently trigger or disabled. Can you link to your XML for the webview activity and the setup Java code and when I get a chance I'll pull my code and compare them to see if there is a noticeable difference?

Comment: Now I tested, and all that my WebView missed was requestFocus, it was not focused. I focused it in code and it navigates in web. You may consider to make it non-focusable or set focus to parent view.

Comment: @PointerNull Strange. Initially I had tried that but then it wouldn't scroll at all. I'll try again using different combinations of setting it in code vs xml, and setting other things as focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `WebViewClient` to suppress clicks in the `WebView`. Then you can scroll the WebView just like simple scroll view instead of jumping on the links within the page. Example `CustomWebViewClient`:

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent (WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
        return true; //Ignore clicks
    }
}
```

Then set this `CustomWebViewClient` to your webview:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient() {
            ...
        });
```